# A conjecture on representing $\sum\limits_{k=0} ^m (-1)^ka^{m-k}b^k$ as sum of powers of $(a+b)$.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, conjectures

**UPATE:** I asked this question on MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463924/conjecture-displaystyle-sum-k-0-m-1kam-kbk-abm-m1-left-s).

---

I was solving problem  1.2.52 in "An introduction to the theory of numbers by by Ivan Niven, Herbert S. Zuckerman, Hugh L. Montgomery"

> Show that if $\gcd(a, b)$ =
> $1$ and $p$ is an odd prime, then $\displaystyle \gcd\left(a+b, \frac{a^p+b^p}{a+b}\right)=1$ or $p$.

So I tried to represent $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0} ^m (-1)^ka^{m-k}b^k$ as sum of powers of $a+b$ For any even number $m$ that is one less than a prime number .

$$\sum_{k=0} ^2 (-1)^k a^{2-k}b^k = (a+b)^2 -3ab$$
$$\sum_{k=0} ^4 (-1)^k a^{4-k}b^k = (a+b)^4 -5(ab)(a+b)^2 +5(ab)^2$$
$$\sum_{k=0} ^6 (-1)^k a^{6-k}b^k = (a+b)^6 -7(ab)(a+b)^4 +7 \cdot 2(ab)^2(a+b)^2 -7(ab)^3$$

I noticed that
$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0} ^m (-1)^ka^{m-k}b^k=(a+b)^m +(m+1)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\frac m 2} g_m(k)(-(ab))^k  (a+b)^{m-2k}\right)$ where $g_m(k): \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ (I was not able to find a way to determine  of $g_m(k)$ )

I couldn't prove this pattern or find $g_m(k )$ or  prove that $\displaystyle  \sum_{k=0} ^2 (-1)^k a^{2-k}b^k $ can be represented  as sum of powers of $a+b$ For any even number $m$ that is one less than a prime number.

### So my question is: How to prove that for any $m=p-1$ such that $p$ is prime number $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0} ^m (-1)^ka^{m-k}b^k=(a+b)^m +(m+1)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\frac m 2} g_m(k)(-(ab))^k  (a+b)^{m-2k}\right)$ and determine $g_m(k)$.

---

I don't think it is possible represent   $\displaystyle  \sum_{k=0} ^m (-1)^ka^{m-k}b^k$  in the form  $\displaystyle(a+b)^m +(m+1)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\frac m 2} g_m(k)(-(ab))^k  (a+b)^{m-2k}\right)$.

I don't think this will work for any even number because I noticed that in any even rows $m$ that is above a prime row $p$ i.e ($p=m+1$) in this image

[image]

There is a very interesting property $\dbinom{m}{k}+(-1)^{k+1} |p $ for example $253+1|11 , \  \  15-1 | 7$ and so on but for any other even row this doesn't hold.

Comment: I fixed some formatting issue in the post.

Comment: When $m=p-1$, ${m \choose k} \equiv (-1)^k \pmod p$ is a well-known congruence.

Comment: @RenéGyI am new to number theory so I didn't know that, can you give me a link to the proof

Comment: We have $ {p-1 \choose k}  = \prod_{i=1}^k (\frac{p}{i}-1) \equiv \prod_{i=1}^k (-1)  \bmod p$. That is $ {p-1 \choose k}   \equiv  (-1)^k  \bmod p$.

Comment: @Sil Prove that for any $m=p-1$ $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0} ^m (-1)^ka^{m-k}b^k=(a+b)^m +(m+1)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\frac m 2} g_m(k)(-(ab))^k  (a+b)^{m-2k}\right)$ and find $g_m(k) $

Comment: To show that such a representation exists, use the fact that $\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k a^{m-k}b^k$ is symmetric polynomial in $a$ and $b$, and every symmetric polynomial is a polynomial in the elementary symmetric functions $a+b$ and $ab$ (with integer coefficients). You can also work out the coefficient of $(a+b)^m$ is 1 in this expression by noticing that the coefficient of $a^m$ and $b^m$ is 1 in the target polynomial.